# Multiple related resources in chef recipe

Tags: automation, chef

I need to run some commands depending on a result of previous execution, which again depends on some package being installed.

On the first run, I'd expect something like:

```
install package "XXX"
get output from XXX
for each line in output:
    if missing, use XXX to add
    if unknown, use XXX to delete
```

The problem is that when I do the logic in top level of the recipe, then the `get output` part will happen before package `XXX` is installed. I'd really like to just order those parts by using a ruby block (enforcing execution when the resources are processed), but then it seems I cannot nest execute resources inside of a ruby block resource.

How can I implement this correctly?

The recipe goes something like this:

```
flavors_bag = data_bag_item('nova', 'flavors')

cmd = Chef::ShellOut.new("nova-manage flavor list")
flavors = cmd.run_command.stdout

flavors_bag['spec'].each do |flavor|
  execute "nova-manage flavor create #{flavor['name']} #{flavor['ram']*1024} #{flavor['cpu']} #{flavor['disk']} #{flavor['id']}" do
    action :run
    not_if {flavors.include? flavor['name']}
  end
end

['some', 'old', 'values'].each do |flavor_name|
  execute "nova-manage flavor delete #{flavor_name}" do
    action :run
    only_if {flavors.include? flavor_name}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your recipe? Unfortunately I can't find a reference, but I remember reading on the Opscode site that Chef runs Resources of the same type as a batch. So, how you are calling for the install (and the subsequent add/delete) can matter.

You may want to look at the [Execute Resource](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Resources#Resources-Execute)

[Chef documenation: sometimes you want to make sure that a resource is configured before anything else.](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Evaluate+and+Run+Resources+at+Compile+Time)

Comment: Updated the question with the code I'm using (fails on the first run because of missing `nova-manage` command) - the package is listed to install before, but the Chef::ShellOut runs before all resources.